SwiftUI FileDocument: Modify the default save panel
Is it possible to change the default save dialog that appears when creating a document based MacOS app in SwiftUI?
I have a basic FileDocument struct that gets called to a view using a DocumentGroup scene.
struct MyFile: FileDocument {
    static let readableContentTypes: [UTType] = [.myFileType]
    static let writeableContentTypes: [UTType] = [.myFileType]
    
    var list: [String]
    
    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents!
        let JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            try list = JSONDecoder.decode([String].self, from: data)
        } catch {
            throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
        }
    }
    
    
    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        let JSONEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        JSONEncoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
        
        do {
            data = try JSONEncoder.encode(self.list)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            throw CocoaError(.fileWriteUnknown)
        }
        return .init(regularFileWithContents: data)
    }
}

This gets called at the DocumentGroup
DocumentGroup(newDocument: MyFile(), editor: { document in
    ContentView(document: document.$document)
})

But when I save the file, I want the save dialog that appears to have something like a 'Tags' textField that can also store information about the file.
Something similar to this:

From what I can find, there isn't much information about this other than manually creating an NSSavePanel class and overriding the current save function
